# Struct reference in another struct

Tags: solidity

I have 2 structs like this:

```
struct A { ... }
struct B { A a; }

A[] aa;
B[] bb;

function createB(uint256 aIndex) {
  A storage a = aa[aIndex];
  B memory b = B({a: a});

  bb.push(b);
}
```

Instances of `A` stored in array and in

I have couple of questions about it:

1. Why doesn't works explicit declaration of `a` inside `B` as `storage`, i.e. `A storage a` doesn't compile?
2. Am I right that anyway I'll have `b.a` as storage ref, not as copy of original `A` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Sorry, but why do you need explicit declaration of `a` as `storage`? Why not use:

```
function createB(uint256 aIndex) {
  B memory b = B({a: aa[aIndex]});

  bb.push(b);
}
```

2) No. Either way you will store copy.

Comment: Because I have 2 arrays of different structs and want to be able to refers from one to another without copying.

Comment: It is sad that one storage struct unable to keep storage reference to another, just tested it. Thanks.